# Unable to create a keras model. Error message expected dense_67_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1, 36)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-2

I am using keras to create a model using the url  https://github.com/tensorflow/workshops/blob/master/extras/keras-bag-of-words/keras-bow-model.ipynb as the reference/guide.

The only difference in the approach between the one mentioned in the above URL and my approach is in encoding.

My vocabulary has only 35 words. So, I do a one hot encoding for each word like below

[0000001000.....00]   //column length is 35

So, my sentence with 3 words after encoded will look like

[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 1]]

[[0 0 0 ... 0 1 0 0]]

[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 1 0]]]

and the shape looks like this (3, 1, 36)

I wish to pass thousands of encoded sentence for training and each of the sentence has different size of words. When I print the shape of the encoded sentence, I got 
(3, 1, 36)
(4, 1, 36)
(7, 1, 36)
(4, 1, 36)
(9, 1, 36)
(3, 1, 36)
.
.
.
.
(5, 1, 36)

Now, I need to pass this to the model

I created  a model as below

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
max_words = 1000
# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
# model.fit trains the model
# The validation_split param tells Keras what % of our training data should 
 be used in the validation set
# You can see the validation loss decreasing slowly when you run this
# Because val_loss is no longer decreasing we stop training to prevent overfitting
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                validation_split=0.1,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

After running this, I got an error message 
**Error when checking input: expected dense_71_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 1, 36)**

I am sure I am doing something fundamentally wrong. But not sure how to fix this as I am a novice user and extensive search too didnt help me.

Any help  in resolving this will be a huge help for me. Thanks

Comment: you encoding isnt going to work ( even if you had the right input shape on the model --which you dont) unless you trained a single sentence at a time.

Comment: why this encoding .. what are you attempting to model. Why not use the same encoding as the author of the notebook?

Comment: thats because I don't want to go with bag of word model. For my requirement, sequence matters a lot.

Comment: this is what I though when I say your new question. I'll give answer over there.

Comment: @putonspectacles - Thanks a lot.

Comment: @putonspectacles  - Any pointers on this as this would be greatly beneficial and I am quite stuck..

Comment: I've been working on your answer, hit some snags. see your other question. close this one.